# Thiessen Polygon Issue

Tags: dictionary, polygon, arcgis, voronoi

I am trying to run a thiessen polygon. But every time I run it get the second picture. The first is a raster of precipitation for every point. How do I get a thiessen polygon to look just like the shape of Texas and not a rectangle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The first is a raster of precipitation for every point

Do you mean a grid of points instead of raster ?

Assuming yes, running Thiessen polygon will create a several square or rectangle polygons that you can clip using:

analysis tools --> extract --> clip

or by tiping clip(analysis) in the search box.

You just need to have the Texas boundary or polygon as clip feature.

Gilbert.